# Python Elasticsearch update_by_query not working

Tags: elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch, update-by-query

I want to update multiple docs using update_by_query in elasticsearch.py (version 7.13.1)

My query is:

```
es_query = {
    "query": {
        "match": {"user_id.keyword": user_id}
        # "bool": {
        #     "must": [{"term": {"user_id": {"value": user_id}}}]
        # }
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.user_level = params.user_level",
        "params": {
            "user_level": user_level
        },
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}

result = es.update_by_query(index='articles', doc_type='_doc', body=es_query, wait_for_completion=True,
                            ignore=[400, 404], conflicts='proceed', refresh='true')
```

I have tried with match as well as must query but the docs are not getting updated with no such error.

The response that I get is this:

```
{'took': 1, 'timed_out': False, 'total': 0, 'updated': 0, 'deleted': 0, 'batches': 0, 'version_conflicts': 0, 'noops': 0, 'retries': {'bulk': 0, 'search': 0}, 'throttled_millis': 0, 'requests_per_second': -1.0, 'throttled_until_millis': 0, 'failures': []}
```

If I run the same query on Kibana, it works as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sound like your query do not match anythings, so wrong user_id maybe ?

Comment: I have checked for valid user id, for which it is working on Kibana

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by calling the `requests.post()` API call instead of using `update_by_query()`.

Then the code looks like this:

```
url = os.environ['ES_HOST'] + "/articles/_update_by_query"
result = requests.post(url=url, json=es_query, headers={"content-type": "application/json"})
```